# Bad request returned from google cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get a google cloud function to work to open a stripe checkout, currently it isn't working however.

This is the function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
)


const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.secret_key);


exports.createStripeCheckout2 = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onCall(async(req, res) => {

  const cust = req.body.customerId
  const price = req.body.priceId
  const quantity = req.body.students
  const quantityA = Number(quantity)

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    mode: 'subscription',
    allow_promotion_codes: true,
    customer: 'cus_MQrpENhbL84RFD',  
    line_items: [
      {
        price: 'price_1LaJC1CKMdmWgnyspBbFet9v',
        // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    success_url: `https://learning-platform-835f9.web.app/`,
    cancel_url: `https://learning-platform-835f9.web.app/`,
  });
  res.redirect(session.url);
});
```

Returns the following:

> {"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

With this in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`onCall()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.https#httpsoncall) is different than [`onRequest()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.https#httpsonrequest) and the parameters in the function are not `Request` and `Response` from Express. It seems you are trying to call this function like a REST API using `fetch` or equivalent. If so, you must sent the request with the details mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) like the `Content-Type` header must be present and the body must have a `data` property.

In this case, using `onRequest` function should work keeping rest of the code as it is.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Very much appreciate your help with this and on all the other questions you have answered for me over the last weeks/months

Comment: Do you know how I would go about passing the values from a form on my react front end to use in this cloud function? I was using the req.body lines to do this when the function was being run on my local server through node and express. Would that same method work with the google cloud function?

Comment: @PeterBonnebaigt yes, when you are using `onRequest()` it's essentially same as an Express app. (You do pass an Express instance in it). Cloud functions is just a serverless platform where you deploy your code. The Express app will run the same.