# Firebase functions onRequest to onCall

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How do I pass this `onRequest` function to `onCall`? I am working from my localhost with emulators. Could someone give me some guidance, I have tried to follow the documentation of [functions.https.onCall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) but I can't understand if I have to do any previous step.

```
export const getFileInformation = functions.https.onRequest( (req, res) => {

  return cors( req, res, () => {

    const urls = [
      `url1`,
      `url2`,
      `url3`
    ];

    const urlsCalls: any[] = [];
    const resultados: any[] = [];

    urls.forEach( url => {
      urlsCalls.push(axios.get(url));
    });

    Promise.allSettled(urlsCalls)
    .then( response => {
      response.map( (element: any) => {
        const item = element.value.data;
        resultados.push(item);
      });
      console.log(resultados);
      res.json(resultados);
    })
    .catch( error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  } );
});
```

I'm trying something as simple as this:

```
export const getFileInformation2 = functions.https.onCall( (data, context) => {
  return { msg: 'Hello from Firebase!' };
});
```

But I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
```

How should I address an `onCall` function?

Comment: The code shows `onRequest`. Can you show your code that you tried for `onCall()`?

Comment: @Dharmaraj i have edited my question please see what i am trying

Comment: How are you calling the `onCall()` Cloud Function? Can you please share your client side code? I doubt you are not using Firebase SDK to call it and missing some required parameters just like in this post: [Bad request returned from google cloud function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73755211/bad-request-returned-from-google-cloud-function/73755252#73755252)

Comment: I am calling it from my localhost with emulators `http://localhost:5001/[myProjectName]/us-central1/getFileInformation2`. From what I read I have to include a header and some other parameters, do you have any concrete example please?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code that you are using to call the function? maybe the Axios/fetch request so it might be a bit easier to explain?

Comment: I call it from the url, first I run: `firebase emulators:start --only functions` and it generates the url `http://localhost:5001/[myProjectName]/us-central1/getFileInformation2` then I go to the browser and paste the url and it throws me that error, additionally in the emulators logs it throws me: ` "severity": "WARNING", "message": "Request has invalid method. GET"

Comment: Hi @PacoZevallos , have you checked my posted answer? Let me know if you have questions or clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS Callable functions must be called using the POST method, the Content-Type must be `application/json`, and the body must contain a field called `data` for the data to be passed to the method.

See sample body:

```
{
    "data": {
        "someKey": "someValue"
    }
}
```

When pasting the URL directly to a browser it is called using the `GET` method which returns an error `Request has invalid method. GET` and the reason you're getting `{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}` is you're not passing the required field which is `data` on your request body.

You can call a `https.onCall` using curl or Postman.
Sample call using curl:

```
curl -d '{"data": {"someKey": "someValue"}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:5001/[myProjectName]/us-central1/getFileInformation2
```

---

For more information, you may check :

- [Protocol specification for https.onCall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference)

Comment: Thanks @marc-anthony for the explanation, I have been able to understand the approach of the onCall functions. In this case I was able to get the response by calling from my frontend: `getInfo() {
    const functions = getFunctions(getApp());
    connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001);

    const getInfo = httpsCallable(functions, 'getFileInformation2')
    getInfo().then( (result) => {
      console.log(result.data);
    })
  }`

Comment: @PacoZevallos , Could you post this as an answer so it can also help the community.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví asi:

index.ts

```
export const getFileInformation2 = functions.https.onCall( (data, context) => {

    const urls = [
      `url1`,
      `url2`,
      `url3`
    ];

    const urlsCalls: any[] = [];
    const resultados: any[] = [];

    urls.forEach( url => {
      return urlsCalls.push(axios.get(url));
    });

    return Promise.allSettled(urlsCalls)
    .then( response => {
      response.map( (element: any) => {
        const item = element.value.data;
        resultados.push(item);
      });
      console.log(resultados);
      return resultados
    })
    .catch( error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

});
```

Luego ejecuto emulators:

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

Luego lo llamo desde mi frontEnd:

component.ts

```
getFilesInformation() {
    const functions = getFunctions(getApp());
    connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001);

    const getInfo = httpsCallable(functions, 'getFileInformation2')
    getInfo().then( (result: any) => {
      console.log(result.data);
    })
  }
```